# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x740078008d

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-firestore, android-ndk, segmentation-fault, native-crash-reporting

We are getting the crash mentioned in the title. It occurs quite often and randomly. It seem to occur only on Android 11.

I have the tombstone file, which I paste below. But I am having issues also using ndk-stack, because when issuing the command:

```
ndk-stack -sym /Users/UserNameExample/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/renderscript/lib/blas/arm64-v8a -dump /Users/UserNameExample/Desktop/tombstone02
```

I get the exact same source file in the prompt.

Ideally, I would like ndk to work and understand why it is not translating my tombstone. Otherwise, as a second alternative, by looking at the tombstone, would anyone pls have any hints on how to track this down ?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'OPPO/CPH1919EEA/OP4845L1:11/RKQ1.200928.002/1636803154694:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-12-12 14:12:07+0100
pid: 10105, tid: 10105, name: es.dev.virtualshop  >>> com.dev.virtualshop <<<
uid: 10320
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  b4000071594a846d  x2  fffffffffffffffd  x3  0819080000006023
    x4  2360000000081908  x5  0819080000006023  x6  2360000000081908  x7  b4000071aa8a8630
    x8  0000007fe4039c60  x9  0000000000000041  x10 b4000071594a8440  x11 b4000071594a8440
    x12 b4000071aa8a89f0  x13 b4000071aa8a8b30  x14 0000000000000030  x15 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
    x16 000000724827b5c0  x17 0000007248bfe200  x18 000000724ed96000  x19 0000000000000000
    x20 0000000000000000  x21 b400007134377c20  x22 000000000000003d  x23 000000000000000e
    x24 0000000000000020  x25 b4000071aa8aa759  x26 000000000000000e  x27 b4000071aa8aa750
    x28 000000000000001b  x29 0000007fe4039d80
    lr  000000724824f1d4  sp  0000007fe4039c00  pc  000000724824f1ec  pst 0000000060000000

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000000401ec  /system/lib64/libandroidfw.so (android::Theme::SetTo(android::Theme const&)+2104) (BuildId: dd55aee448a41ca5dd33562f5abdc552)
      #01 pc 000000000012209c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeThemeCopy(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, long, long)+132) (BuildId: a54426a2b2bfe5ad975341aa6c0e7841)
      #02 pc 000000000021ea50  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+176) (BuildId: 75f57aa82d8d6889edeed86525a613a1631601e4)
      #03 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #04 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #05 pc 0000000000318290  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #06 pc 000000000030f67c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+696) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #07 pc 0000000000682a90  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStaticRange+412) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #08 pc 000000000012dc94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static_range+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #09 pc 00000000003b7f00  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.AssetManager.setThemeTo+28)
      #10 pc 00000000006803fc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+1132) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #11 pc 000000000012db14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_range+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #12 pc 00000000003c3698  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.setTo+28)
      #13 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #14 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #15 pc 00000000003c30c4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.Resources$Theme.setTo+8)
      #16 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #17 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #18 pc 00000000001aaa0a  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~L2_UsRVtNSOKCZeGvFhDhQ==/com.dev.virtualshop-gSflxpM7-xq4qewsKph26Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme+62)
      #19 pc 000000000067f1f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1248) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #20 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #21 pc 00000000001aa87e  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~L2_UsRVtNSOKCZeGvFhDhQ==/com.dev.virtualshop-gSflxpM7-xq4qewsKph26Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme+26)
      #22 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #23 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #24 pc 000000000027f0a6  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x12ad000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme+46)
      #25 pc 000000000067f1f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1248) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #26 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #27 pc 000000000027f11c  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x12ad000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme+12)
      #28 pc 000000000067d930  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+2468) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #29 pc 000000000012d894  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_super+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #30 pc 00000000001cf384  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Activity.setTheme)
      #31 pc 000000000067d930  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+2468) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #32 pc 000000000012d894  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_super+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #33 pc 000000000019d0fc  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~L2_UsRVtNSOKCZeGvFhDhQ==/com.dev.virtualshop-gSflxpM7-xq4qewsKph26Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme)
      #34 pc 0000000000305bb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12828692043800420071)+268) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #35 pc 000000000030dba8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #36 pc 000000000030ef90  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #37 pc 0000000000174fb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+45680) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #38 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #39 pc 00000000001bae68  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity)
      #40 pc 0000000000305cc0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12828692043800420071)+532) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #41 pc 000000000030dba8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #42 pc 000000000030ef90  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #43 pc 0000000000174fb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+45680) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #44 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #45 pc 00000000001bacf8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity)
      #46 pc 0000000000305cc0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12828692043800420071)+532) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #47 pc 000000000030dba8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #48 pc 000000000030e5a0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+968) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #49 pc 000000000067c8d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+848) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #50 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #51 pc 00000000002c26ea  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute+134)
      #52 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #53 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #54 pc 00000000002c4ada  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks+286)
      #55 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #56 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #57 pc 00000000002c495c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute+228)
      #58 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #59 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #60 pc 00000000001b9fe0  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+292)
      #61 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #62 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #63 pc 00000000003d141a  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x97a000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+38)
      #64 pc 000000000067cb78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #65 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #66 pc 00000000004039ce  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x97a000) (android.os.Looper.loop+666)
      #67 pc 0000000000305bb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12828692043800420071)+268) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #68 pc 000000000030dba8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #69 pc 000000000030ef90  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #70 pc 0000000000177f40  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+57848) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #71 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #72 pc 00000000001c57ac  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main)
      #73 pc 0000000000305cc0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12828692043800420071)+532) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #74 pc 000000000066b5f0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #75 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #76 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #77 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #78 pc 00000000005562bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1364) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #79 pc 00000000004d53d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #80 pc 00000000000947f4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180) (BuildId: f5ff44d4e96af9e82722863cdcbb11a1fae640f2)
      #81 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #82 pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #83 pc 0000000000318290  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #84 pc 000000000030e5bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #85 pc 000000000067c8d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+848) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #86 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #87 pc 00000000005286ba  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x12ad000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
      #88 pc 0000000000305bb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12828692043800420071)+268) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #89 pc 000000000066b5f0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #90 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #91 pc 00000000008fac74  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2756) (BuildId: 75f57aa82d8d6889edeed86525a613a1631601e4)
      #92 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #93 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #94 pc 0000000000554cf8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+448) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #95 pc 00000000005551ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #96 pc 0000000000438fdc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656) (BuildId: 0ba3e7738c2ac9a4d1da77e310c0b257)
      #97 pc 000000000009c424  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: a54426a2b2bfe5ad975341aa6c0e7841)
      #98 pc 00000000000a4160  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+856) (BuildId: a54426a2b2bfe5ad975341aa6c0e7841)
      #99 pc 0000000000003674  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1580) (BuildId: 9349370b830e2b77b835dee3aff71480)
      #100 pc 0000000000073a5c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: 1ca28d785d6567d2b225cf978ef04de5)
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it looks like the crash happens when the app is being launched (`#39`), when it is in the process of setting the app's theme (`#30`): I can't think of a reason why this would only happen on Android 11; possibly it's looking for some resource that it didn't use to before?

Comment: Yes, it must have something to do with the application of the theme,
but I confirm that it is only on Android 11. The crash occurs in three scenarios: 1) when starting the Home Activity, right after the MainActivity with a LaunchTheme,
2) when I instantiating a new fragment, 3) when instantiating a new Activity. It likely concerns an external library rather than my code

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I filed a bug, which currently appears to be ignored by Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213477925

Answer (score -2):

try these three steps:

1. invalidate and restart android studio
2. close/kill all the opened applications to keep all the memory to your developing app.
3. reinstall your app from android studio.